# Is it possible to create an AWS AMI from a Docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ami

I have a Docker image in my AWS ECR which I want to convert to an AWS AMI for creating an instance with the environment.

**Reason for trying to use an AMI over a Docker container**

I had to run computationally intensive ML tasks in my Docker container inside an `m4.xlarge` instance on some text files. However, with Docker, the CPU utilization of the instance is reaching 100% and the script is getting killed pre-maturely.

However, it is running fine in the same instance from outside of Docker.

---

So, I want to move to AMI's from Docker, however I also want to leverage Docker for the environment creation and the speed of testing which it enables in my local.

So, **is it possible to create an AMI out of the Docker image** which I test and deploy to my ECS registry?

Comment: This is the standard tool for building AMIs: https://www.packer.io. I am pretty sure it does what you are describing.

Comment: Sounds like you are running in CPU resource limits.  Is this a EC2 instance running Docker, or the AWS ECS?  Talking about ECR implies you might be using ECS.  ECS carves up each host into 1024 cpu 'shares'.

If you run with a hard cpu limit configured, at a total under the total shares, you shouldn't see an issue

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to create an AWS AMIs out of docker image although there is an opensource tool which can create/build AWS AMIs out of a docker file but only supported instructions are ENV, RUN, COPY and ADD, other instructions will just be ignored.

**Open-source Tool for Building AWS AMI from Docker file**

https://github.com/mickep76/docker-build-ami

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docker-build-ami/0.1.3

So if you are really interested in trying out go ahead with creating a proper docker file from your docker image. For that you can refer following links

[Is it possible to extract the Dockerfile from a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24360556/6148152)

[How to generate a Dockerfile from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19104847/6148152)

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that there is a problem or misconfiguration with the docker image or docker.
You mention the instance runs the same script outside of docker without a problem?
Then better create an AMI of the instance with the running script and you don't need docker at all.
Having a script running within docker could at most mean the docker configuration limits CPU, but not that the host CPU goes to 100% and kills the script.
You should try running a docker container with the same image, but on a sleep10000 run, so you can go within the container, run the script of interest and see what is failing.