# AWS ECS : recover lost images

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have accidentally deleted my ECR's images and i dont have the code for some clusters anymore,
however I still have the current ECS running correctly with status : Active.

Is there anyway i can recover the content files in these clusters??

Thanks !

Comment: I've never done it on AWS, but you can get information on the running container with docker history, but I think you're better off recreating the images in case your cluster starts failing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360556/is-it-possible-to-extract-the-dockerfile-from-a-docker-container

Comment: Are they running on EC2 or Fargate? If EC2, you should be able to go into the EC2 host and get the image.

Answer (score 0):

I archived that by connecting into the EC2 instance and typing :

```
sudo docker images
```

then copying the image name and typing :

```
docker save {{img_name}}  > my_lostimage.tar
```