# Automated Dockerfile generator

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to generate a `Dockerfile` as a "top-down approach". I have a fully configured system and would like to make an image from it to ship it away. It was built to a base image.

Comment: can you elaborate? I do not understand

Comment: Did you try centurylink/dockerfile-from-image to generate the Dockerfile from exist image directly ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847/how-to-generate-a-dockerfile-from-an-image/30793515#30793515)

Comment: @BMW: Yes, but it is working with existing images. My image would be new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is to create a Docker *image*, rather than a Dockerfile.  You can just tar up your filesystem and import it into Docker; e.g., something like:

```
tar --one-file-system -cf- / | docker import - myimagename
```

The `--one-file-system` option is to prevent `tar` from archiving things like `/sys` and `/proc`.  This will get you a Docker image containing a copy of the filesystem; whether or not this will actually be useful probably depends on what you're trying to do with it.