# Docker: Is it necessary to mount a new partition

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, docker, mount

I want to install a product on Docker. It was previously installed on an EC2-server of Amazon.

The installation starts with creating a mount point `/product`. Than they partition a disk with `fdisk` and they're creating a new partition. After that they create a filesystem and mount the new partition to `/product`.

I'm not familiar with this but it seems to me that the main goal is to install the product on one new disk.

The installation was performed on an `Ubuntu:14.04`
So I just want to start like this:

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

Performing the same installation instructions and create an image of the container.

Is it necessary to perform something of the mount instructions or can I just start the installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> perform something of the mount instructions

Not exactly.
The best practice is to define your installation step in a [`Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), starting with `from ubuntu:14.04`, and including a `VOLUME /mount` in order to [declare `/mount` as a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume).

This is preferred to a `docker run` + (work) + (exit) + `docker commit`, because with a Dockerfile, you can easily repeat the installation process with a simple `docker build`. And you keep the specification of that installation written in the Dockerfile.

The alternative would be to go your way, and then try to **[extract a Dockerfile from the resulting image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30793515/6309)**.

In that case, [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#commit) allows to apply some Dockerfile instruction to the image created.
Typically, the mount would be done at that time:

```
docker commit -c='VOLUME /mount'` <yourcontainer> <yourimage>`
```

Comment: Yes I know a Dockerfile and use it often. But this installation is pretty long and complex. So It would be difficult to write it in one Dockerfile (surely at the beginning). Is it possible to generate a Dockerfile from a container or image?

Comment: @Jenson Not that I know of.

Comment: @Jenson I stand corrected. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Jenson But as you comment, the resulting Dockerfile might not include *everything*.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain me what the VOLUME /mount will be translated in shell commands? (So I first try to perform it inside the container and later on I translate into a Dockerfile)