# How to show a dockerfile of image docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, inspect

I download a image from docker repository and Im trying to display the Dockerfile of 'X' image to create my own Dockerfile with the same structure to experiment with him. Im using this command:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Image}}' 'here paste the id of image'
```

That command return a 'sha256', some like this:

```
sha256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

but I need a command to display a json file with configuration of Dockerfile. Someone know how can I do this?
Sorry if the format or the question is not ok, Im a beginner!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The raw output, as described in "[How to generate a Dockerfile from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444917/6309)", would be:

```
docker history --no-trunc <IMAGE_ID>
```

But a more complete output would be from [`CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image`](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image)

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
 centurylink/dockerfile-from-image <IMAGE_TAG_OR_ID>
```

Note there [were limitations](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image#limitations).

**In 2020**, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30793515/6309):

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm alpine/dfimage \
  -sV=1.36 <IMAGE_TAG_OR_ID>
```

Comment: Reportedly centurylink/dockerfile-from-image doesn't work (didn't work on my side either): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847/how-to-generate-a-dockerfile-from-an-image/48444917#comment77612772_30793515
alpine/dfimage mentioned in the answer commented by the comment referred works fine as of 2020-07-21.