# Updating a docker image without the original Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am working on Flask app running on ec2 server inside a docker image.

The old dev seems to have removed the original Dockerfile, and I can't seem to find any instructions on a way to push my changes into to the docker image with out the original.

I can copy my changes manually using:

> docker cp newChanges.py doc:/root/doc/server_python/

but I can't seem to find a way to restart flask. I know this is not the ideal solution but it's the only idea I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one way to add `newChanges.py` to existing image and commit that image with a new tag so you will have a fall back option if you face any issue.

Suppose you run alpine official image and you don't have DockerFile

Everytime you restart the image you will not have your `newChanges.py`

```
docker run --rm -name alpine alpine
```

Use `ls` inside the image to see a list of existing files that are created in Dockerfile.

```
docker cp newChanges.py alpine:/
```

Run `ls` and verify your file was copied over

**Next Step**

To commit these changes to your running container do the following:

```
Docker ps
```

Get the container ID and run:

```
docker commit 4efdd58eea8a updated_alpine_image
```

Now run your alpine image and you will the see the updated changes as suppose

```
docker run -it updated_alpine_image
```

This is what you will see in your update_alpine_image with having DockerFile
[image]

This is how you can rebuild the image from existing image. You can also try @uncletall answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

- If you just want to restart after `docker cp`, you can just `docker stop $your_container`, then `docker start $your_container`.
- If you want to update `newChanges.py` to docker image without original `Dockerfile`, you can use `docker export -o $your_tar_name.tar $your_container`, then `docker import $your_tar_name.tar $your_new_image:tag`. Later, always reserve the `tar` to backup server for future use.
- If you want continue to develop later use a `Dockerfile` in the future for further changes:

  - you can use `docker commit` to generate a new image, and use `docker push` to push it to `dockerhub` with the name something like `my_docker_id/my_image_name:v1.0`
  - Your new `Dockerfile`:

```
    FROM my_docker_id/my_image_name:v1.0
    # your new thing here
    ADD another_new_change.py /root/
    # others
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to examine the history of the image, from there you can probably re-create the Dockerfile. Try using `docker history --no-trunc image-name`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847/how-to-generate-a-dockerfile-from-an-image) for more details