# If I have locally docker image. How Could I list what is installed on it?

Tags: image, docker

For instance I have this image locally https://github.com/topflight-technology/docker-images/tree/master/go-testing. Then system lost all info about it. So how we could recreate the image docker file? Or at list get the list what tools are installed.

```
docker ps -a
```

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
f047b64e79d1        topflighttech/go-testing   "/bin/sh"           28 seconds ago      Exited (0) 26 seconds ago                       friendly_leakey
```

So I need to investigate docker container or strait forward image?

Comment: The link you provided also seems to have a Dockerfile, and you seem to have launched the container with an interactive shell; both of these things should be good for looking around.

Comment: Here I should check first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847/how-to-generate-a-dockerfile-from-an-image.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the history of an image by running `docker history --no-trunc your_image:tag`. With no other resource available, this might help you to recreate the Dockerfile.

Comment: thx! Sorry it was so trivial but now I get it :)

Comment: Ok! To make it real good let`s try to create script to recreate docker file :)

Comment: No need to feel sorry. :) I also learned something here from the comment of David Maze – very cool (and probably better) way!