# Can the Dockerfile be retrieved back from a docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

Since I consider a Dockerfile to be the recipe instructions that lead up to a result, the docker image, I wanted to know if docker images provide a way to read out those instructions used.

In essence, given I have a docker image, is there a way to know the content of the Dockerfile that created it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847/how-to-generate-a-dockerfile-from-an-image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a Dockerfile from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847/how-to-generate-a-dockerfile-from-an-image)