# How to get the deployment.yaml file for MSSQL cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-devops

I am installing the SQL Server cluster in Kubernetes setup using the below document.

[Check here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/deployment-guidance?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)

I am able to install the cluster successfully. But I need to customize the deployment by specifying the custom docker image, add additional containers.

**May I know how to get the deployment YAML file & Dockerfile for all the images in the running containers?**

I have tried "kubectl edit", but not able to edit required details.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way of doing that is using something like:

```
kubectl get deployment -n %yournamespace% -o yaml > export.yaml
```

Comment: you may also add the `--export` flag to get a yaml you can easily modify before submitting again onto servers

Comment: "true dat", but it also warns that the flag is deprecated

Comment: oh ! did not know that :/ do you know what will replace this flag ? will `get -o yaml` do some `export` by default ?

Comment: no idea, sorry. I just know that I have an alias for `kubectl get -o yaml --export` and it always complains about `--export` being retired soon

Answer (score 0):

For Kubernetes YAML files you can use:

```
kubectl get <pod,svc,all,etc> <name> --export=true -o yaml
```

or

```
kubectl get <pod,svc,all,etc> <name> -o yaml
```

For Docker Dockerfiles there is whole [post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847) which explain how to create a dockerfile from an image.

Answer (score 0):

[Kubernetes Cheat Sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) is a good source for `kubectl` commands.

Let's say your deployments are created in `develop` namespace. Below command will help you to get a `yaml` out of your deployment, `--export` flag will remove the cluster specific information.

```
kubectl get deploy <your-deployment-name> --namespace=develop -o yaml --export > your-deployment.yaml
```

Below command will help you to get a `json` out of your deployment.

```
kubectl get deploy <your-deployment-name> --namespace=develop -o json --export > your-deployment.yaml
```