# building docker image with jhipster monolith app and pushing to my dockerhub

Tags: docker, jhipster

I have created a monolith app using jhipster. 
I ran ./gradlew -Pprod bootJar jibDockerBuild --offline which created the onlinestore docker image on my local.

Now there are couple of things that I am not able to get my head around:
1. where do I put the configuration so that the created docker image can be pushed to my own docker hub. let's say I have created a docker hub registry for my app mandaltu123/onlinestore:latest.

Answer (score 0):

Do following:

1. Login to your new registry with command : `docker login`
2. Tag your image to push using : `docker tag myonlineStore mandaltu123/onlinestore:latest`
3. Push the image using : `docker push mandaltu123/onlinestore:latest`

Comment: Thanks ankidaemon, this should work. I wanted to know that in jhipster autogenerated code, I do not see a docker file. Is there a way to add these configurations to some config in jhipster app so that image creation can be done automatically with my passed in docker registry ?

Comment: dockerfile you can extract from the image, look at this thread-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847/how-to-generate-a-dockerfile-from-an-image

Comment: Jhipster uses jib to build docker images. You can build the image with Gradle/maven https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#-building-and-running-a-docker-image-of-your-application. You can define where to push the image and how to login at the registry via -Djib.to.x parameters.