# Unable to create Dockerfile from a Docker image due to permissions denied error

Tags: docker

I am trying to extract Dockerfile from Docker image.Taking look at a [popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30793515/10834788), I executed the following commands:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm alpine/dfimage -sV=1.36 quay.io/opendatahub/spark-cluster-image:spark24
```

Got the following error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.36/images/create?fromImage=quay.io%2Fopendatahub%2Fspark-cluster-image&tag=spark24": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

How do I get the corresponding Dockerfile for this image?

Comment: Where does that image come from?  Looking at places like GitHub repositories for a Dockerfile might be a little more reliable than trying to reconstruct it from the built image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run with `sudo` command.

```
sudo docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm alpine/dfimage -sV=1.36 quay.io/opendatahub/spark-cluster-image:spark24
```

or add permissions

```
If you would like to use Docker as a non-root user, you should now consider
adding your user to the "docker" group with something like:

  sudo usermod -aG docker your-user
```

Comment: Remember that it's very easy to root the host if you can run any `docker` command; consider the security implications before adding yourself to the `docker` group.

Comment: What's the other way to execute docker ? If not `sudo` nor adding user to `docker` group.

Comment: I'd prefer `sudo` on anything that's not a single-user developer machine.

Comment: that's why I have suggested both ways of doing it.