# How to generate a Dockerfile from an image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

One of our `X` employee has created an docker image. Currently i need to update the same image which was created by him. But unfortunately i couldn't find the `Dockerfile` for the image.

Is it possible to generate a dockerfile from an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this answer is good from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847/how-to-generate-a-dockerfile-from-an-image)

This worked for me from the answers

```
docker pull chenzj/dfimage

alias dfimage="docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm chenzj/dfimage"

dfimage image_id
```

you need the image id  - not the name

e.g

```
$docker images

REPOSITORY   TAG  IMAGE ID  CREATED  SIZE
```

so the third column.

There is still work to do with it and it all depends how the docker image was created

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this command:

```
alias dfimage="docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm alpine/dfimage"
dfimage -sV=1.36 IMAGE_NAME:IMAGE_TAG
```

And note at Dockerfile

[image]